# How to find and change words that appeared on string that match with array

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array

My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat
            [tag] => animal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat women
            [tag] => human
        )

)
```

My string

```
$string = 'cat is not cat women, my women at home';
```

How to find and change words that appeared on the $string that match with the $array? so I can get a new string like this:

> animal is not human, my women at home

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a combination of `foreach`, `if`, `strpos`, `str_replace | preg_replace`, make an attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version

```
$array = [['name' => 'cat', 'tag' => 'animal'], ['name' => 'cat women', 'tag' => 'human']];
$string = 'cat is not cat women, my women at home';

usort($array, function($a, $b) { // first sort by length of varchar
    return strlen($a['name']) < strlen($b['name']);
});

$string = str_replace( array_column($array, "name"), array_column($array, "tag"), $string);

echo $string;
```

Output: animal is not human, my women at home

Comment: You could replace the `foreach` with `$string = str_replace( array_column($subs, "name"), array_column($subs, "tag"), $string);` (as long as PHP >=5.5)

Comment: terimakasih banyak sudah mencoba untuk memberikan solusi untuk saya :) @Sakezzz

Comment: terimakasih juga koreksi nya, saya sangat mengapresiasinya :) @NigelRen

Answer (score 1):

Please try this logic:

```
$arrrrr = array
(
    "0" => array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "cat",
            "tag" => "animal"
        ),

    "1" => array
        (
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "cat women",
            "tag" => "human"
        )

);

$string = "cat is not cat women, my women at home";
foreach($arrrrr as $sarr){
  $pos = strpos($string, strtolower($sarr['name']));
    if($pos !==false){          
       $string =  substr_replace($string,$sarr['tag'],$pos,strlen($sarr['name']));

    }
}
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
animal is not human, my women at home
```

I think it would be helpful for you.

Comment: @dany, Please this solution

Comment: Not sure how reliable this solution is as `"cat women is not cat women, my women at home"` gives `animal women is not human, my women at home`

Comment: @NigelRen thanks FYI, but I tested it many times it gives `"animal is not human, my women at home"`

Comment: My point is that it may work for that 1 original string, but if you changed the string (as in my previous comment) then the code breaks.  IMHO a good solution looks at the problem as a whole rather than 1 single example.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, next time I will remember. I have given it as per the current string. Actually, there is a static string as he defined.

Comment: terimaksih @GufranHasan sudah mencoba membantu saya :)